# A system of determinant equations: solutions, or at least existence thereof?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

While doing some physics, I have encountered an interesting problem, which reduces to the following:

Given a collection of scalars $a_i,b_j$ and real, symmetric $N\times N$ matrices $M_i$, we wish to find scalars $x_i$ that simultaneously solve the $N$ determinant equations
$$
0 = \det\left[ \sum_{i=0}^N (a_i + b_j x_i)M_i\right]
$$
for $j=1,\ldots,N$. Under what conditions does a solution exist, and when it does, how does one find it in general?

I have explicitly solved such a problem in a specific $N=2$ case, which wasn't very hard, but I am for now stumped as to how one would tackle it at the level of generality I present here.

In the cases I'm interested in, the elements of $M_i$ have a rather systematic form (I can provide the lengthy-ish definition if needed), but the resulting matrices are not mutually commuting, so no simplifications can be made based on simultaneous diagonalization. I suppose the problem would be quite a lot easier if that was the case.

Comment: One condition which is clearly sufficient is $b_{j}\neq0$ for all $j$, because then $x_{i}=-\frac{a_{i}}{b_{j}}$ is a solution. Do you want to exclude this kind of trivial solutions?

Comment: @Andijvie - that is not a solution, since $-a_i/b_j$ varies with $j$ whereas $x_i$ does not (assuming not all $b_j$ are the same). That is the crux: the same collection $x_i$ must simultaneously solve all the equations for different $j$. Making the argument of the determinant zero, rather than merely singular, is a lost cause in the concrete examples I'm dealing with.

Comment: All the determinant does here is insure the matrix sum is singular. You can drop it, and just look for $x_i$ that make all $N$ matrices singular. This frees the summation inside from the determinant's non-linear grip, and allows you the freedom to manipulate it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair True; maybe I should have written "is singular" instead. I just have a habit of thinking in terms of determinants being zero, since they are the the only "singularity test" I know that makes a straightforwardly computable, smooth function of the elements of a matrix, which unlocks a lot of nice analytic and numeric approaches. That doesn't apply very well to this case, though.

Comment: I notice that $i$ ranges from $0$ to $N$, meaning that there are $N+1$ of the $a_i, x_i, M_i$, but $j$ only ranges from $1$ to $N$, so there are only $N$ of the $b_j$, and the matrices themselves are only $N \times N$ dimensional. Is that how it is supposed to be, or should the lower limit on $i$ be $1$ as well?

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's how it's supposed to be, and I suspect it is necessary to have it so, or at least that it greatly relaxes the conditions for a solution to exist. (This is just gathered from how the explicit examples I solved behaved.)

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but a geometric interpretation of your problem that might be useful to think about:

For a given $x = (x_0, \dots x_N)$, let $Q_x = \sum_i x_iM_i$. In particular, $Q_a = \sum_i a_iM_i$.

The collection of all $N\times N$ symmetric matrices forms an $\binom{N+1}{2}$-dimensional vector space and the $M_i$, assuming they are linearly independent, span an $N+1$ dimensional subspace $\cal Q$ of it. The $Q_x$ for various $x$ are exactly the elements of this space. For any fixed $x$, the set $L_x = \{Q_a + tQ_x\mid t\in \Bbb R\}$ is an affine line in $\cal Q$. The $b_j$ form $N$ points on that line.

$\det Q = 0$ forms an $N$ dimensional hypersurface in $\cal Q$. I do not know enough to say much about what this hypersurface looks like. But "hypersurface" itself is likely not entirely accurate. It will be a variety, which allows for the surface to bifurcate in certain locations (for example, two crossing lines counts as a variety, but not a curve, because the point of intersection does not look like $\Bbb R$).

Picking $x$ to solve the equation amounts to choosing a line passing through $Q_a$ that intersects the hypersurface in $N$ points whose distances from $Q_a$ are in exactly the ratios of the $b_j$. That is, if the $j$-th point of intersection is at a distance of $d_j$ from $Q_a$, then for all $j, \frac{d_j}{d_1} = \frac{b_j}{b_1}$. (Getting $d_1$ to be the right distance from $Q_a$ to satisfy the $b_1$ equation can be accomplished by simply rescaling $x$.)

It seems to me that this would be very hard to accomplish as $N$ gets bigger. So tight limitations on $M_i$ and $b_j$ will be necessary for solutions.

Comment: That sure is a fresh way to approach it compared to the various algebraic stuff I've been trying so far. (There's just a small error in the dimension, which I'll correct.)

Comment: In the case $N=2$, $\det Q=0$ forms an elliptic double-cone centred on the $\mathrm{tr}\, Q$-axis. Then, granted the $M_i$ are linearly independent, I strongly feel like there should be solutions for all $a_i,b_i$, although I haven't proven it. But you sure are correct in that it seems exceedingly difficult and unlikely to find solutions in $N>2$.